# Kotlin: suppress warning for function starting with uppercase letter

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

The Kotlin [guide on coding conventions](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html#function-names) says factory functions may start with an uppercase letter,

> Exception: factory functions used to create instances of classes can have the same name as the class being created:
>
> ```
>     abstract class Foo { ... }
>
>     class FooImpl : Foo { ... }
>
>     fun Foo(): Foo { return FooImpl(...) }
> ```

The code inspector in android studio did not get the memo, however; it complains about the upcase letter. I realize I can go into settings and modify the rule, but (1) I don't want to make that global change, and (2) I don't want other people using my code to get the warning. I just wish to suppress the warning coming from this one line with a @Suppress directive (or some other way).

And I can't seem to find a list of all @Suppress directives -- where
is it?

And where do I file a bug report for this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To suppress any warning in Kotlin, press Alt-Enter, then the right arrow key and select the suppress action from the context menu, as shown on the attached screenshot.

[image: Suppress quickfix]

The issue for this problem [has already been filed](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-20438).

Comment: As I mentioned, I'm not interested in just disabling it locally on my system because I don't want others to get this warning. There appears to no @Suppress directive or other means of disabling it everywhere for everyone. Is that true?

Comment: I've attached the screenshot to clarify how you can find the suppress action. The action will insert an annotation into your code, so it won't be local to your system.

Comment: Thanks. But ... Jesus, why the heck is it under "Rename"? And while I appreciate your response, the reason for my confusion is that you pointed me to these IDE fiddlings instead of answering the question: What is the Suppress directive? The answer is "FunctionName", thanks. I wish I could find that list of Suppress directives. Does it exist?

Comment: I didn't answer the question because developers are not expected to enter the `@Suppress` directives manually. That's also why we don't publish a list of all possible `@Suppress` values.

Comment: Oh, it's much faster to write the suppressions so that one never has to deal with walking through warnings and fiddling with misnamed submenus. Also, if the Suppress values are published then I'll know when I'll finally be able to suppress spelling/typo false positives, which I still can't do in Kotlin, right? The list would also answer that question -- too bad it doesn't have an obvious answer, right?

Comment: I don't see how looking for an entry in a list of 1000 possible options is faster than pressing four keys (Alt-Enter, Right, Up, Enter).

Comment: You misunderstood. Knowing the suppression value and writing it is faster than walking through warnings and fiddling with mislabeled submenus. Let me know when the spelling suppression directive comes out. Or keep it secret. Up to you.

Comment: As @NicholasWagner said, the correct answer is `@Suppress("FunctionName")`

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if you have your Jetpack Compose plugin disabled. Just go to

File->Settings->Plugins and type Compose in Search Field.

[image: Settings]